# Water is leaking thru my smoke detector and water is pooled up around the bottom of the ac in the attic

Tags: water-damage

Came home and heard smoke alarm going off went into bedroom and water is pouring from smoke detector. I go

Comment: Has the condensate pipe fallen off?

Comment: Either that or the drain got clogged and the float switch is busted.

Answer (score 1):

Air conditioneres make water from atmospheric humidity

they all have a drain,  some have a pump  that feeds the drain.

It could be that the pump is broken or that the drain is blocked leaking, or disconnected.